# Wifi adapter not functioning after Ubuntu 15.10 upgrade from 15.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

**Edit:**

Still nothing I have gone through every link I can find. The Module loads but I never get to generating the Wlan0 adapter.

And rfkill list does not show a wifi adapter.. I am about to resort to disassembling this thing and attempting to replace the WIFI adapter.

Hours I have spent and I am no closer to a solution. Has anyone confirmed the 15.10 even supports this adapter??

---

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 a few days ago. So of course the lame Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n is giving me a hard time.

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have been a Linux user for about a year now and have mostly been able to find answers looking around here on my own but now I am stumped.

If there is any other info I can provide please let me know.

I started here.......

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

The closest I got was driver would install but it would it would show "*-network:1 UNCLAIMED" or something to that effect.

I found a script that someone (sorry cant remember who). It seems to pull a lot of valid info. So I posted the info below.

Any Ideas?

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Oct 2015 14:55 EDT -0400

Booted last: 30 Oct 2015 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, acpi, osi=, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6605]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp. Broadcom BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 06a3:8021 Saitek PLC Eclipse II Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
bcma                   53248  0
wmi                    20480  1 asus_wmi
video                  36864  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.130  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1052 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:819238 (819.2 KB)  TX bytes:109925 (109.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver xxx.xxx.1.1
search xxx.rr.com

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1288     1  0 14:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.2/0000:04:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.130/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = xxx.xxx.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     6DF74A7EF5817B6F27A5CB0
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-16-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        6A:1B:9C:21:F0:4A:B8:6E:D1:B7:CE:D6:CA:21:35:40:FC:8E:45:B6
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x4365 (wl)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.414764] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   13.414901] bcma: bus0: Found chip with id 43142, rev 0x01 and package 0x08
[   13.414927] bcma: bus0: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x28, class 0x0)
[   13.414948] bcma: bus0: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x21, class 0x0)
[   13.414990] bcma: bus0: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x16, class 0x0)
[   13.415040] bcma: bus0: Core 3 found: UNKNOWN (manuf 0x43B, id 0x368, rev 0x00, class 0x0)
[   13.429977] bcma: bus0: Bus registered
[   14.988110] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   14.988120] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   20.134672] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   20.134740] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   22.842250] r8169 0000:04:00.0 eth0: link up
[   22.842266] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  139.685982] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please see the duplicate. You need `bcmwl-kernel-source` and a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

OK after everything here is what worked. I may have caused most of this mess myself (In fact I am sure I did). This link the files inside and just built it with

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7

And here is how to use these files

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-install-dsc-file-in-linux-896928/

Thanks for the support and I hope some day I can give back to the Linux world when I have gotten over the learning hump.